# How to ignore different values in a column you want to group in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with records that I want to group. Some column can contain a little different values, for example:

ID---PRODUCT---AMOUNT
1----Candy--------23.44
1----CAND--------14.42
1----CAND---------8.18

I want to group the records by ID and summarize the amount, finally I want to ignore the product by simply saying I want to use the first value.

This is my SQL statement.

```
 SELECT [ID]
      ,[PRODUCT]
      ,sum([AMOUNT]) AMOUNT
  FROM [TABLE]
  GROUP BY [ID], [PRODUCT]
```

If I don't write [PRODUCT] in my group by I get this error:

> "Column 'PRODUCT' is invalid in the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: possible duplicate of [GROUP BY ignoring an attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364429/group-by-ignoring-an-attribute)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to aggregate all columns that are not in your `group by` clause. You could use `min()` to get the alphabetically smallest

```
  SELECT [ID]
      ,min([PRODUCT]) PRODUCT
      ,sum([AMOUNT]) AMOUNT
  FROM [TABLE]
  GROUP BY [ID]
```

Or remove the `product` entirely

```
  SELECT [ID], sum([AMOUNT]) AMOUNT
  FROM [TABLE]
  GROUP BY [ID]
```

Comment: I can't remove the product I want to show it, the first statement did it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you use group by, each column in the select clause must be either defined via an Aggregate function (like MAX, MIN, AVG, ...) or must be included in the group by clause.

Solution:

Add all columns in the SELECT clause into the GROUP BY clause or remove the column that causing problem from the SELECT clause.

Answer (score 0):

This should work
    CREATE TABLE Table1
        ([ID] int, [PRODUCT] varchar(6), [AMOUNT] numeric);

```
INSERT INTO Table1
    ([ID], [PRODUCT], [AMOUNT])
VALUES
    (1, 'Candy', 23.44),
    (1, 'CAND', 14.42),
    (1, 'CAND', 8.18);
select *, (select top 1 PRODUCT from Table1 T1 where t.ID=t1.id) Product 
    from (SELECT [ID]      
    ,sum([AMOUNT]) AMOUNT
      FROM [TABLE1]
    GROUP BY [ID])T
```